# Running a command on Apache2 not sure about the result

Tags: apache2, mod-expires

ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled | grep expires

Its returning nothing does that mean I don't have mod_expires on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. I found more information related to this [here](http://www.debuntu.org/2006/06/15/66-how-to-enable-apache-modules-under-debian-based-system).